# which is better, create all after delete all relation OR delete or create after check if exist in database

Tags: database

Say `Blog` has tags `A`, `B`, `C`

When updating blog tags to `B`, `C`, `D`, should I:

1. Delete all `A`, `B`, `C` tag relation and create `B`, `C`, `D` relation
2. remove `A` and create `D` relation after getting the previous tag list and compare?

Which is better practice?

```
Blog
----------
|id|title|

tag
---------
|id|name|

BlogHasTag
-----------------
|id|blogId|tagId|
```

Comment: you should show ur data table

Comment: @JimmyN I add table info

Answer (score 0):

> Remove A and create D relation after get previous tag list and compare

In my opinion, the better practice in terms of database should be only remove and create the necessary data. `BlogHasTag.id` might wasted if you remove all tags relation and add it back again.

But if you want to prevent additional process to get previous tag list and compare, you can change the way you issue your update statement.

Which kind of update style would you prefer:

1. Issuing the update statement when all edit has been made
2. Issuing the update statement the moment user delete tags A in edit mode